# Automatically install .Net framework in a Setup Project

Tags: .net, winforms, installation

I have a setup project in visual studio 2010 to install a winforms and I want the setup to install automatically .Net framework. I put the framework as prerequisite but the installation is not automatic. The User must, after receiving the message that has not .NET installed, open the installer manually. Is there a way to install .Net framework so automatic in my setup?